# Boot a Debian firmware-nonfree netinstall USB device with GRUB2

Tags: grub2, debian-installer, firmware, broadcom, apple

I have an [*Apple MacMini Intel*](http://free_zed.gitlab.io/articles/2014/11/debian-et-macmini-intel/) running a *Debian Stretch* (no BIOS-like boot list, just standard GRUB2).

I would like to boot on a USB device to set a fresh new installation, with the latest [firmware-nonfree netinstall](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/).

I add a custom entry to the GRUB2 menu like this (on a regular Debian session) :

```
$ sudo vi /etc/grub.d/40_custom
menuentry "Debian Netinstall (USB)" {
    set root=(hd0)
    linux /debian/install.amd/vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1 ro
    initrd /debian/install.amd/initrd.gz
}
```

This allow me to run the text mode installer, directly to the language choice, but with a *red* painted backgroud (not the usual color for this netinstaller).

The problem came after the network config : I need to feed my wlan deice with the `b43/*` firmwares.

This USB device loaded with this Netinstall image was OK for installing a laptop (`iwlwifi*` firmware needed) earlier in the week. On a standard BIOS bootlist.

I try some stuff to feed installer with the asked firmwares :

- using the installer shell to `mount /cdrom/firmware/ /lib/firmware/`
- using another USB key with the `firmware` directory of the netinstall image
- using another USB key with the specific files asked (found [here](https://github.com/OpenELEC/wlan-firmware/tree/master/firmware/b43))

None of this worked and the installer keep ask for the firmwares...

### Questions :

- How can I feed the installer with the asked files?
- How can I set GRUB2 custom entry to run installer *from the begining* (the first menu asking for the kind of installation)?
- Why the background is red?